# Starting Program Minimized In C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I'm trying to start up Chrome at a specific address, but I want it to be minimized when it starts. However, with the code I'm using, the program starts normally. How can I make Chrome start minimized in C#?

```
ProcessStartInfo w = new ProcessStartInfo("chrome.exe", "http://pandora.com --new-window");
w.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(w);
```

It's really weird, because I find it to work around 10% of the time, but I can't figure out when it works, and when it doesn't. Is there anything anybody can see that I'm doing incorrectly in my code?

Comment: I can't answer your question definitively but what you will find is that, in some cases, the window that you end up seeing is not actually part of the process that you started.  If the process you start then starts another process then you have no control over that second process.  My guess would be that what you're doing might work if there was not already a Chrome window open but not if there was, but that's just a guess.  One thing you can do to check whether the process you started is the process you see is to compare the ID of the process in your code with the one running in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do something similar (not with Chrome) I realized two things which might be relevant.

First some applications seem to ignore the properties in ProcessStartInfo. To check if it is the case a simple test is to go to the application desktop shortcut and in the properties window change the size to minimized (property called "run"). If the application runs full screen anyway it seems it will also ignores the minimized property in ProcessStartInfo.

To go around it I did the following:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

And once the process started:

```
ShowWindow(aProcess.MainWindowHandle, 6);
```

Where 6 is the value to get the process window minimized.

It works but since my application takes few second to start I had to add a thread sleep between the start of the application and the minimizing.